# Save Channel Entry as Draft

Tags: channel-entries, status, workflow

I want to update a channel entry and save it as a draft. I am the admin but I need someone else to review the changes before it is published. This would be either a new channel entry or an updated one. Much like it's done in WordPress. Is there an adon or can I do it natively in EE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the native entry statuses to accomplish a draft status. If you review the [documentation on statuses](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/statuses.html), you'll see how you can edit the status group and add `draft` alongside `open` and `closed`.

Then, you'll just have to make sure your status group is assigned to the channels you're using to publish the content.

By default, the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag will only show entries with the status of `open`, so none of the content set to `draft` will be visible on the site.

Comment: This is probably the simplest solution to the OP's problem, I think. It sucks that you have to sacrifice your channel's status group, but you gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: Kristin, what else do you use statuses for that would constitute "sacrificing" the status group for workflow purposes? Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Better Workflow](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/better-workflow) for this. It makes life much easier when handling scenarios like what you have here. Another approach I have used, while not as pretty, was to establish statuses, and build a exception to block all but local traffic through a firewall (in this case, using [Big IP from f5](http://www.f5.com/products/big-ip/big-ip-local-traffic-manager/overview/)) and building multiple templates. One of the templates will be prefixed with the exception rule, so if you block all outside traffic but allow internal traffic with say 'internal_', your templates could be 'article' and 'internal_article' where 'article' only displays 'open' status and 'internal_article' displays 'open|draft'.

It's messy and complicated though. That's why I just fold and use Better Workflow.   ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that using Better Workflow will prevent you from using custom Statuses on any of your entries. And while Electric Putty does a phenomenal job supporting BW, it is prone to frequent bugs, so you'll likely spend a lot of time troubleshooting issues as EE and add-ons are updated.

Comment: Good to know about Better Workflow ... Thanks

Comment: @kgrote I'm with you on the statuses. In my cases, I have used other means to achieve what I need from the previously used statuses. As far as the "buggy" bit, I guess I've been pretty lucky thus far. I haven't had to deal with them.   ;)

Comment: I should say the level of bugginess goes up in relation to the number of third-party fieldtypes you use. So if your site isn't particularly complex, you'll probably be fine.